# How to update the transaction fees in private network - normally it is 100 stroops

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, fees

I have updated the config file by putting the below value

```
   COMMANDS=["upgrades?mode=set&upgradetime=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z&basefee=1&basereserve=1"]
```

By using the command 
     stellar-core --c 'info'
it is showing 
          "baseFee" : 1,
         "baseReserve" : 1,

But when I am creating an account, I can check the fees in explorer; it's still 100 stroops.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is there any way we can change the transaction fees?
I have made a private network with 2 nodes.

Comment: How are you creating an account? Programmatically or through the laboratory?

Comment: programmitically. and i have resolved the issue

Comment: @SumanRaj How exactly?